# Interface function in Ethereum contract

Tags: solidity

I was looking at the code on the Ethereum website, what does this code do?

```
interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData); }
```

Available at: https://ethereum.org/token#full-coin-code

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is JavaScript?

Comment: `interface` in many languages is used to define a protocol or object interface, an alternative to an abstract base class. Any class that implements that is assumed to be "conforming" to it and it serves as a sort of type.

Comment: @tadman This is Solidity, not Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

It does nothing as it's an interface. An interface is a way to define constraints so that you can communicate with any object that implements this and know that the functions defined in the interface will existing in the implementation.

```
interface tokenRecipient {
    function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData);
}
```

One example of this would be a way from one contract to communicate to another and looks like an ERC223 implementation for a recipient

In contract you want to communicate to you have to have implemented the tokenRecipient e.g.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

interface tokenRecipient {
    function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData);
}

contract MyContract is tokenRecipient {
    function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) {
        // functionality
    }
}
```

So if we now implement a contract me know that we can interact with any contract that has tokenRecipient implemented e.g.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

interface tokenRecipient {
    function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData);
}

contract RemoteContract {
    function func(address _addr, uint _value) {
        tokenRecipient _tokenRecipient = tokenRecipient(_addr);
        _tokenRecipient.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, address(this), empty);
    }
}
```

It will error if the call fails which is what we need to happen to prevent things such as a token being sent to a contract which cannot do anything with it. As Solidity is atom and works in a transactional way if the contract cannot receive it then it will rollback all functionality already executed.